# Data is not being returned to Django Template, Data Does Exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am having an issue not getting data to return to a template, but this is not happening with other models in the same template. I can properly submit data on another page to this data model (TechnicianLabor) via a form, but the data will not publish from my calls in the html, what am I missing?:

models.py

```
class TicketList(models.Model):
    identifier = models.AutoField(primary_key=True) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(default="Add description for Ticket: ", null=True, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey('ClientCompany', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignment = models.ManyToManyField(TechnicianUser, null=True, blank=True)
    create_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True)


class TechnicianLabor(models.Model):
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(TicketList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    minutes = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
    is_tracked = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(TechnicianUser, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

views.py

```
def apps_tickets_details_view(request, pk):
    tickets = TicketList.objects.get(pk=pk)
    projects = ProjectList.objects.filter(pk=tickets.project_id)
    labors = TechnicianLabor.objects.all()
    comments = TicketComment.objects.filter(ticket_id=tickets)
    comment_count = comments.count()
    technicians = TechnicianUser.objects.all()
    replies = TicketCommentReplies.objects.filter(ticket_id=tickets)
    context = {"tickets":tickets,"comments":comments,"projects":projects,
               "replies":replies, "technicians":technicians, "labors":labors,
               "comment_count":comment_count}
    
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TicketListAddForm(request.POST or None,request.FILES or None, instance=tickets)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(comments)
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Ticket Updates Successfully!")
            #return redirect("apps:tickets.list")
            return redirect(reverse("apps:tickets.details", kwargs={'pk':tickets.pk}))
        else:
            print(form.errors)
            messages.error(request,"Something went wrong!")
            return redirect("apps:tickets.list")
            #return redirect(reverse("apps:tickets.list", kwargs={'pk':tickets.pk}))
    return render(request,'apps/support-tickets/apps-tickets-details.html',context)
```

html

```
<h6 class="card-title mb-4 pb-2">Time Entries</h6
<div class="table-responsive table-card">
    <table class="table align-middle mb-0">
        <thead class="table-light text-muted">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Member</th>
                <th scope="col">Date</th>
                <th scope="col">Duration</th>
                <th scope="col">Timer Idle</th>
                <th scope="col">Tasks Title</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                        <img src="{% static 'images/users/avatar-8.jpg'%}" alt="" class="rounded-circle avatar-xxs">                              
                        <div class="flex-grow-1 ms-2">
                            <a href="{% url 'pages:pages.profile' %}" class="fw-medium"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                             
                </th>                                 
                {% for labor in labors %} 
                    <td>{{labor.at}}</td>                                  
                    <td>3 hrs 12 min</td>
                    <td>05 min</td>                               
                    <td>Apps Pages</td>                               
                {% endfor %}                                        
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I expect these fields to duplicate in the html page, but nothing shows

fields:

```
<td>{{labor.at}}</td>
<td>3 hrs 12 min</td>
<td>05 min</td>
<td>Apps Pages</td>
```

html proof that nothing is returned
[image]

Proof Data Exists from Django Shell:
[image]

Comment: You are looping at the wrong place. But just to see if it will otherwise render, can you temporarily remove the `for loop` and just manually render the four `td`s? See if it's showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User error: I was writing it to the wrong view context